# Replace foreign characters

Tags: php

I need to be able to replace some common foreign characters with English equivalents before I store values into my db.

For example: **æ** replace with **ae** and **ñ** with **n**.

Do I use preg_replace?

Thanks

Comment: This is known as [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your convertable characters in an array, and use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$conversions = array(
    "æ" => "ae",
    "ñ" => "n",
);

$text = str_replace(array_keys($conversions), $conversions, $text);
```

Answer (score 6):

For single character of accents

```
$str = strtr($str, 
  "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÝßàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ",
  "AAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOYSaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy");
```

For `double character` of accents (such as `Æ, æ`)

```
$match   = array('æ', 'Æ');
$replace = array('ae', 'AE');
$str = str_replace($replace, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: +1 for the character set (but I am missing some hungarian ones: `ŐőŰű`;)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with `ASCII//TRANSLIT`:

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

Comment: @ajrael: This does convert 'æ' to 'ae', at least it did when I tried it just now. http://ideone.com/tBewx - Can you give a specific example showing how it doesn't work?

Comment: @Mark [Doesn't work](http://ideone.com/TSOeG) with `ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT`. Edited to `ASCII` as in your working example. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that difference!

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me second-guessing why you're doing this, but..

If this is for search matching: The point of character set collation in a MySQL (for example), is that you can search for "n" and still match "ñ"

IF this is for display purposes: I'd recommend if you have to do this, you do it when you display the text to a user. You can never get your original data back otherwise.