# Strip whitespace from associative array Keys

Tags: php

I have an associative that outputs whitespace in the key and value.  I need to strip the whitespace from first letter and also the last letter and keep the space inbetween.

I have tried

```
$stripResults = array_filter(array_map('trim', $results));
```

This strips the value perfectly but not the key.  How do I strip the key and value?

Comment: Use `array_keys()` that gets an array of all the keys in the array, merge the `array_values()` with a new array and voilla.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove spaces in array keys names in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563369/how-to-remove-spaces-in-array-keys-names-in-php)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keys must be processed separately:

```
$a = array_map('trim', array_keys($stripResults));
$b = array_map('trim', $stripResults);
$stripResults = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Comment: This answer is great.  Only a few lines and does the job very well, thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at this and need to remove or replace spaces that are not at beginning or end of key, you can pass an array to `str_replace`:

```
$my_array = array( 'one 1' => '1', 'two 2' => '2' );
$keys = str_replace( ' ', '', array_keys( $my_array ) );
$results = array_combine( $keys, array_values( $my_array ) );
```

Example:
https://glot.io/snippets/ejej1chzg3

Answer (score 1):

Try this function will help you..

```
function trimArrayKey(&$array)
{
    $array = array_combine(
        array_map(
            function ($str) {
                return str_replace(" ", "_", $str);
            },
            array_keys($array)
        ),
        array_values($array)
    );

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            trimArrayKey($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't solve the problem for my particular scenario, but this did the trick.

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($stripResults as $key => $value) {
    $temp[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}
$stripResults = $temp;
```