# Remove potential characters from beginning only of array keys

Tags: php, arrays, regex, loops

Using php...

I have an array (multidimensional though I'm only worried about the top level in this instance) where the keys are strings that take a variety of forms. Examples of the keys are;

- Fred Smith
- Dr John Paul
- Dr. Mary Ellen
- Bill Driver

I need a function that will remove 'Dr', 'Dr ', 'Dr', 'Dr. ' only from the beginning of any key where they are found. I am currently using this...

```
function fixArrayKey(&$arr) {
$arr = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function ($str) {
            return str_replace(array('Dr. ', 'Dr.', 'Dr ', 'Dr'), '', $str);
        },
        array_keys($arr)
    ),
    array_values($arr)
);
```

}

...which I found in the answers here [How to remove spaces in array keys names in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563369/how-to-remove-spaces-in-array-keys-names-in-php)

It is nearly getting me there, but will act on a match anywhere in the string, so I am ending up with;

- Fred Smith
- John Paul
- Mary Ellen
- Bill iver

I have the feeling that I need to look to using preg_replace() somewhat like this example [Remove a string from the beginning of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517067/remove-a-string-from-the-beginning-of-a-string) and I think I can set a limit in preg_replace() but I'm not sure. I've also looked at ltrim()but it's not quite right. My problem is that I may not find a match, or the match might be 2, 3 or 4 characters long, and there may be matches I do not want to remove in the middle of the string.

Am I looking in the right direction with  preg_replace()?

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~^Dr\.?\s*~', '', $str)`

Comment: On second thought, `preg_replace('~^Dr\b\.?\s*~', '', $str)`  should be better.

Comment: I added an answer with explanations.

Comment: AbraCadaver, no. I'm using the regex from @Wiktor Stribiżew, below, with the word boundary marker in it. It is catching the edge case "Dr.Mary Cross" where there is no space between the prefix and first name. I want to try to work that into your one-liner, which failed for me the first time, and I haven't had a chance to get back to it yet. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to cover all bases with this regex.  This is only the `return` portion that needs to be changed:

```
return preg_replace('/^Dr\.?\s+/', '', $str);
```

- `^` is the beginning of the string replace `Dr`
- Optionally `?` replace `.` after
- Replace 1 or more spaces `\s+` after

However, to eliminate all of that code that you currently have, you could use:

```
$array = array_combine(preg_replace('/^Dr\.?\s+/', '', array_keys($array)), $array);
```

Comment: With the second `?` you risk matching on first names like Draco, Drake, Dreyfus, etc. I would replace it with a `+` for `one or more` spaces instead of a `*`.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that.  I was just following what OP already had at first.

Comment: I can't get the one-liner to work, but I'll puzzle that out. The return with the preg_replace does work, but you have an extra round brace in it. It should be preg_replace('/^Dr\.?\s+/', '', $str);

Comment: Sorry, I had a misplaced `)` in both.  I edited it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `preg_replace` will work for you as you can remove *whole words* easily using the anchors and word boundaries.

Use

```
return preg_replace('~^Dr\b\.?\s*~', '', $str);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQBUnv/1). Note I added `Draco Malfoy` as an additional test string. The regex does not remove `Dr` here. Why See below.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `Dr\b` - a whole word `Dr` (as `\b` is a word boundary)
- `\.?` - one or zero dots
- `\s*` - one or more whitespaces.

Comment: I like the word boundary marker. I wasn't aware of that. This expression works, as well as the one above does too.

Comment: But test with `Draco Malfoy` and you will feel the difference. I think that all other solutions do not check that a *whole word* should only get matched.

Comment: I did test with this one '/^Dr\.?\s+/' from @AbraCadaver and it seems to be ok, even with Draco Malfoy. regex is so elegant :-)

Comment: The regex was wrong, there was `\s*` at the end. Now, it won't work in case there is no whitespace. E.g. [`Dr.Mary Cross`](https://regex101.com/r/J4Zamn/1). It is up to you to mark the accepted answer, but I still believe the only right approach here is with the word boundary.

Comment: Good catch and good point.. and btw... love the regex101 site!

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array(
    'Fred Smith' => true,
    'Dr John Paul' => true,
    'Dr. Mary Ellen' => true,
    'Bill Driver' => true,
);

foreach($names as $key => $val) {
  $temp_key = strtolower(trim(substr($key, 0, 2)));
  if($temp_key == "dr") {
       unset($names[$key]);
       $names[trim(substr($key, 3))] = $val;
  }
}

print_r($names);
```